# Should a comma precede "meaning that"?

Tags: commas

"I have a song, meaning that I'm now a composer." Should there be a comma before "meaning that"? What type of speech is "meaning that" and how do the rules apply?

Here's a [site](http://facweb.furman.edu/~moakes/Powerwrite/partspeech.htm) that puts a comma before "meaning that".

Comment: You certainly need the comma to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an authoritative answer, but you're joining two separate/related ideas which benefit from the distinction, which is [the purpose of a comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/).  So it's not specific to the phrase "meaning that":

> I have a song, so now I'm a composer

feels better than

> I have a song so now I'm a composer